# How can I assign hotkeys for pasting from the clipboard?

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard, copy-paste

I am looking for a way to have some text "permanently" copied to the clipboard and assigned to a hotkey?

Any software suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, [TextExpander](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) might be right up your alley. It allows you to assign custom abbreviations to text snippets and graphics for insertion anywhere.